# Rate limit laravel queue with Redis

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue

I am trying to rate limit one of my laravel queues using the below:

```
Redis::throttle('key')->allow(10)->every(60)->then(function () {
    // Job logic...
}, function () {
    // Could not obtain lock...

    return $this->release(10);
});
```

I don't quite understand what the 'key' is used for, does this need to be unique per job or something that identifies the jobs as a group ( not unique )?

Also, I'm assuming this code is to go into the handle method of the job?

Answer (score 1):

`'key'` is a limiter name - the hash stored in redis that holds number of acquired locks. It is `KEYS[1]` in the [lua script](https://github.com/illuminate/redis/blob/99a089632addfce44e6befd65440c43eb34abc1b/Limiters/DurationLimiter.php#L116) that actually implement the rate limiting.

To put it simple, if you have multiple invocations of `Redis::throttle` with the same argument, all of them will contribute to the quota. It is not required to be unique, but using it with different decays may result with unexpected behaviour, as it seems to be used in `reset()` function only. I imagine there are usecases where you may need to use the same hash name  for multiple jobs, but it must be quite rare.